# How do I inject different SwiftMailer mailers into different services in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, swiftmailer

I have a Symfony 2.8 project that requires usage of two separate mailing services (eg. Google SMTP and Yahoo SMTP). I have configured them according to the docs:

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: mailer_google
    mailers:
        mailer_google:
            transport: smtp
            host: %mailer_google_host%
            port: %mailer_google_port%
            encryption: tls
            username: %mailer_google_username%
            password: %mailer_google_password%
        mailer_yahoo:
            transport: smtp
            host: %mailer_yahoo_host%
            port: %mailer_yahoo_port%
            encryption: tls
            username: %mailer_yahoo_username%
            password: %mailer_yahoo_password%
```

*The values for the `%variables%` are all defined in `parameters.yml`, which are not relevant here.*

I'm trying to use a custom Mailer class which is used to define two different services, like this:

```
aalaap.services.mailer_google:
    class: Aalaap\AppBundle\Services\Mail\Mailer
    arguments:
      - @mailer
      - '%mailer_google_sender%'

aalaap.services.mailer_yahoo:
    class: Aalaap\AppBundle\Services\Mail\Mailer
    arguments:
      - @mailer_yahoo
      - '%mailer_yahoo_sender%'
```

Now, because the default mailer is set to `mailer_google`, in the first service definition, only specifying `@mailer` works fine. However, the second service can't find `@mailer_yahoo`.

> ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
>   The service "aalaap.services.mailer_yahoo" has a dependency on a non-existent service "mailer_yahoo".

I've tried it with `@mailer.mailer_yahoo`, but that doesn't work either. If I change the first service definition to use the specific `@mailer_google` instead of just the default `@mailer`, that doesn't work either. No luck with `@swiftmailer.mailers.mailer_yahoo`.

How do I inject the second (or non-default) mailer into a service?

Comment: I think the primary service is `swiftmailer`. Try running this command in console and check what service options you have from container. `php bin/console debug:swiftmailer`

Comment: Did you tried @swiftmailer.mailer.mailer_yahoo (not @swiftmailer.mailers.mailer_yahoo) ?

Comment: @UgoT. I *just* figured this out right after posting the question! I almost always figure out the answer myself after posting questions on this site. Anyway - if you post this as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: @RyanVincent Not duplicate, because this is specifically about injection problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is how to setup multiple mailers accounts and handle injection with Symfony :

Setup the swiftmailer config :

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: mailer_google
    mailers:
        mailer_google:
            transport: smtp
            host: %mailer_google_host%
            port: %mailer_google_port%
            encryption: tls
            username: %mailer_google_username%
            password: %mailer_google_password%
        mailer_yahoo:
            transport: smtp
            host: %mailer_yahoo_host%
            port: %mailer_yahoo_port%
            encryption: tls
            username: %mailer_yahoo_username%
            password: %mailer_yahoo_password%
```

Then inject the wanted mailer (for example, google mailer) in services this way :

```
aalaap.services.mailer_google:
    class: Aalaap\AppBundle\Services\Mail\Mailer
    arguments:
      - @swiftmailer.mailer.mailer_google
      - '%mailer_google_sender%'
```

Or (because in that case google mailer is the default mailer) :

```
aalaap.services.mailer_google:
    class: Aalaap\AppBundle\Services\Mail\Mailer
    arguments:
      - @swiftmailer.mailer.default_mailer
      - '%mailer_google_sender%'
```